# Ajax Call is failing for form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

can anyone help me in fixing this issue. the JQuery call is not invoked.
I dont see any java script error or js file error.
fiddler version is https://jsfiddle.net/Ln3kwpbc/

It would be great if some one cofirms me if i have missed something.

```
var cognite_ajax = {



  postRemoveCallback: function(targetUrl, removeTarget, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: targetUrl,
      success: function(response, data) {
        $('#' + removeTarget).remove();
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }
    });
  },


  postReplaceCallback: function(targetUrl, replaceTarget, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: targetUrl,
      success: function(response, data) {
        $('#' + replaceTarget).html(response);
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }
    });
  },


  postAppendCallback: function(targetUrl, appendTarget, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: targetUrl,
      success: function(response, data) {
        $('#' + appendTarget).append(response);
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }
    });
  },


  postPrependCallback: function(targetUrl, prependTarget, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: targetUrl,
      success: function(response, data) {
        $('#' + prependTarget).prepend(response);
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }
    });
  },


  initAjaxForm: function(formId) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions('', '', '', false, false, false, false));
  },


  initAjaxFormCallback: function(formId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, '', false, false, false, false));
  },


  initAjaxFormReplace: function(formId, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, true, false, false, false));
  },


  initAjaxFormAppend: function(formId, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, true, false, false));
  },


  initAjaxFormPrepend: function(formId, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, false, true, false));
  },


  initAjaxFormRemove: function(formId, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, false, false, true));
  },


  ajaxSubmitForm: function(formId, formTargetAction) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions('', '', '', false, false, false, false));
  },


  ajaxSubmitFormCallback: function(formId, formTargetAction, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, '', false, false, false, false));
  },


  //ajaxSubmitReplace: function (formId, formTargetAction, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  //    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
  //    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, true, false, false, false));
  //},

  ajaxSubmitAppend: function(formId, formTargetAction, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, true, false, false));
  },


  ajaxSubmitReplace: function(formId, formTargetAction, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, false, true, false));
  },

  ajaxSubmitPrepend: function(formId, formTargetAction, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, false, true, false));
  },


  ajaxSubmitRemove: function(formId, formTargetAction, updateTargetId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cognite_ajax.ajaxSetFormAction(formId, formTargetAction);
    $('#' + formId).ajaxSubmit(cognite_ajax.ajaxOptions(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, false, false, false, true));
  },


  ajaxOptions: function(successCallback, errorCallback, updateTargetId, isReplace, isAppend, isPrepend, isRemove) {
    return {
      datype: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(response, data) {
        if (data == "success") {
          if (isReplace == true) {
            $('#' + updateTargetId).html(response);
          } else if (isAppend == true) {
            $('#' + updateTargetId).append(response);
          } else if (isPrepend == true) {
            $('#' + updateTargetId).prepend(response);
          } else if (isRemove == true) {
            $('#' + updateTargetId).remove();
          }

          // post-submit callback   
          if (typeof successCallback == "function") {
            successCallback();
          }
        }
      },
      error: function(e, data) {
        // post-submit callback   
        if (typeof errorCallback == "function") {
          errorCallback();
        }
      }
    };
  },


  ajaxSetFormAction: function(form, action) {
    if (action != undefined && action != null && action != '') {
      $('#' + form).get(0).setAttribute('action', action);
    }
  }
}
```